# Nest SQL (Hana) Sequences

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, sequence, hana

I am pretty new to db sql, hdb and stuff. So let's say that in my db I have 3 entities. Contract, Item, Bill. Each Contract has an Item and each Item has a Bill. For this situation, as far as I know, it is recommended to use a sequence in order to generate the id and make sure it won't be a duplicate. My problem is if I should really use that or find another way because with sequence I have only 2 options (for the moment):

1. 1 sequence for Contract. For each contract, 1 sequence to count each Contract's Item and for each Item one sequence to count the Item's Bill.
2. Keep three sequences and every time I add a row, let's say I add an Item, I count how many items area already in the database and start the sequence from that number and increment it, which in my opinion cuts out all the charm of sequence (although I am very new to HDB and SQL and everything)

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the question? Counting dependent rows in tables coupled via foreign keys/associations is a trivial query that does not require the information to be captured in its own column. If there is application meaning to the value of e.g. a BILL's ID (say, that it's legally required that the range has no gaps and all BILL IDs are accounted for) then sequences are not an option, as they can't guarantee that.